# Error from Laravel to AJAX fileupload

Tags: ajax, validation, file-upload, laravel-5

I have an AJAX upload that sends the uploaded file (image in this case) to a function in Laravel 5.3. There I have this validation check in said function:

```
...

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:512',
]);

// If validator fails return this error to AJAX
if($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json('error', 422);
}

...
```

How would I be able to set the `response()->json('error', 422)` with a custom error. Now I only get an error that the file upload has failed. I would like more feedback then that.

For example: let the user know his file is to large or let the user know his extension is not allowed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get error messages from validator and send it to response, here is example.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'error' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ], 422);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, works! I wrote it shorter btw, but the idea remains: `return response()->json($validator->getMessageBag()->all(), 422);`